# Symfony: how to force one choice in a multiple ChoiceType field?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a manyToMany relation between entities `Member` and `Activity`.
One **activity can be collective** (several members take part in it).
On creation of an activity by a member, I let the user specify who are the members involved.

So in my form I use a multiple `EntityType` field which allows to choose amongst all the members.
I would like to set the member creating the activity as default choice (I know how to do that), but I don't know **how to prevent it to be unselected**.

In other words, I want the member creating the activity being selected by default without it being possible to unselect it, while it would still be possible to add other members.

Is there a way to configure the `ChoiceType` (EntityType) to do this?

Comment: The only idea I came across is to bind event listener on this field and check if it's included.

Comment: I don't know for the ChoiceType field, but a workaround would be to add the creator to the activity in your controller, if the form is valid. I assume the creator must be logged in to create an activity.

Comment: I'd probably just check the members after form is posted/valid and if the current user was not in the collection because they unselected themselves, re-add them. A little hacky but simple. If their membership is implied/mandatory you could also possibly not even have it as a selection option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, since it looks like there's no easy solution, I'll try to change the way I'm handling the problem.